# Record count not set for this vector container

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

When I run:

```
SELECT anum as anum, COUNT(*) as callCount, SUM(dur*1) as callDuration, COUNT(distinct bnum) as voiceBnumCount, COUNT(distinct cdrref) as longCallCount
FROM hdfs.`/data/files/{171221}*` as t1 WHERE `t1`.`direction` IN ('up') AND `t1`.`anum_code` IN ('FIRSTANUM') 
AND CONCAT(sdate, ' ', stime) BETWEEN '17.12.21 14.39.58' AND '17.12.21 17.40.00' 
GROUP BY (anum) HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30 AND SUM(dur*1)/60 >= 150
LIMIT 10
```

It raise

org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalStateException: Record count not set for this vector container Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: 1c199e3b-d680-4264-88c5-437a97516a75 on master:31010]

simple err log:

```
2018-11-29 20:38:42,552 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:foreman] INFO  o.a.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman - Query text for query id 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62: SELECT anum as anum, COUNT(*) as callCount, SUM(dur*1) as callDuration, COUNT(distinct bnum) as voiceBnumCount, COUNT(distinct cdrref) as longCallCount
FROM hdfs.`/data/files/{171221}*` as t1 WHERE `t1`.`direction` IN ('moc') AND `t1`.`anum_code` IN ('62_XL') 
AND CONCAT(sdate, ' ', stime) BETWEEN '17.12.21 14.39.58' AND '17.12.21 17.40.00' 
GROUP BY (anum) HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30 AND SUM(dur*1)/60 >= 150
LIMIT 10
2018-11-29 20:38:42,665 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:4:1] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:4:1: State change requested AWAITING_ALLOCATION --> RUNNING
...
2018-11-29 20:38:42,759 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:5:3] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.f.FragmentStatusReporter - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:5:3: State to report: FINISHED
2018-11-29 20:38:42,759 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.p.impl.join.HashJoinBatch - Memory limit 40 MB bytes
2018-11-29 20:38:42,759 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.p.impl.join.HashJoinBatch - Memory limit 40 MB bytes
2018-11-29 20:38:42,759 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:0:0: State change requested AWAITING_ALLOCATION --> RUNNING
2018-11-29 20:38:42,759 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.f.FragmentStatusReporter - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:0:0: State to report: RUNNING
...
2018-11-29 20:38:44,218 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:2:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.f.FragmentStatusReporter - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:2:0: State to report: FINISHED
2018-11-29 20:38:44,232 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.p.i.u.UnorderedReceiverBatch - Informing senders of request to terminate sending.
2018-11-29 20:38:44,232 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] WARN  o.a.d.e.w.b.ControlMessageHandler - Dropping request for early fragment termination for path 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:1:0 -> 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:0:0 as path to executor unavailable.
2018-11-29 20:38:44,406 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:6:1] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:6:1: State change requested RUNNING --> FINISHED
2018-11-29 20:38:44,406 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:6:1] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.f.FragmentStatusReporter - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:6:1: State to report: FINISHED
...
2018-11-29 20:38:44,963 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:0:0: State change requested RUNNING --> FAILED
2018-11-29 20:38:44,965 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:0:0: State change requested FAILED --> FINISHED
2018-11-29 20:38:44,965 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] ERROR o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalStateException: Record count not set for this vector container

Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: 1c199e3b-d680-4264-88c5-437a97516a75 on master:31010]
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalStateException: Record count not set for this vector container

Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: 1c199e3b-d680-4264-88c5-437a97516a75 on master:31010]
    at org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException$Builder.build(UserException.java:633) ~[drill-common-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.sendFinalState(FragmentExecutor.java:361) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.cleanup(FragmentExecutor.java:216) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run(FragmentExecutor.java:327) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.common.SelfCleaningRunnable.run(SelfCleaningRunnable.java:38) [drill-common-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Record count not set for this vector container
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.VectorContainer.getRecordCount(VectorContainer.java:394) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.RecordBatchSizer.<init>(RecordBatchSizer.java:714) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.RecordBatchSizer.<init>(RecordBatchSizer.java:698) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.common.HashTableTemplate$BatchHolder.getActualSize(HashTableTemplate.java:442) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.common.HashTableTemplate.getActualSize(HashTableTemplate.java:901) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.common.HashTableTemplate.makeDebugString(HashTableTemplate.java:910) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.common.HashPartition.makeDebugString(HashPartition.java:580) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.join.HashJoinBatch.makeDebugString(HashJoinBatch.java:1017) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.join.HashJoinBatch.executeBuildPhase(HashJoinBatch.java:829) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.join.HashJoinBatch.innerNext(HashJoinBatch.java:415) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:172) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:119) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:109) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.innerNext(AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.java:63) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.limit.LimitRecordBatch.innerNext(LimitRecordBatch.java:87) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:172) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:119) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:109) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.innerNext(AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.java:63) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.limit.LimitRecordBatch.innerNext(LimitRecordBatch.java:87) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:172) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:119) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:109) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.innerNext(AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.java:63) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:172) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:119) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:109) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.innerNext(AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.java:63) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.project.ProjectRecordBatch.innerNext(ProjectRecordBatch.java:142) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:172) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:119) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:109) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.innerNext(AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.java:63) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.project.ProjectRecordBatch.innerNext(ProjectRecordBatch.java:142) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:172) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next(BaseRootExec.java:103) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScreenCreator$ScreenRoot.innerNext(ScreenCreator.java:83) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next(BaseRootExec.java:93) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor$1.run(FragmentExecutor.java:294) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor$1.run(FragmentExecutor.java:281) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run(FragmentExecutor.java:281) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
2018-11-29 20:38:44,969 [qtp717308094-635] ERROR o.a.d.e.server.rest.QueryResources - Query from Web UI Failed
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalStateException: Record count not set for this vector container

Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: 1c199e3b-d680-4264-88c5-437a97516a75 on master:31010]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.QueryWrapper.run(QueryWrapper.java:115) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.QueryResources.submitQueryJSON(QueryResources.java:72) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.QueryResources.submitQuery(QueryResources.java:87) ~[drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297) [jersey-common-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023) [jersey-server-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.8.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738) [jetty-servlet-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:551) [jetty-servlet-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:219) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478) [jetty-servlet-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232) [jetty-server-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534) [jetty-io-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607) [jetty-util-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536) [jetty-util-9.1.5.v20140505.jar:9.1.5.v20140505]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
2018-11-29 20:38:44,973 [2400141c-c721-c327-9199-19ec95ea5b62:frag:0:0] WARN  o.a.d.e.w.f.QueryStateProcessor - Dropping request to move to COMPLETED state as query is already at FAILED state (which is terminal).
```

full err log:

## https://pastebin.com/1AGTVSjx

And that's only in development machine. Which I assume because memory configuration problem only (?).

In production mode, with same query the error is (cannot provide more, not have access):

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: RESOURCE ERROR: One or more nodes ran out of memory while executing the query. Unable to allocate buffer of size 8192 due to memory limit (41943040). Current allocation: 41943040 Fragment 3:0 [Error Id: 45ab7e51-b563-4fff-9908-33208b895ee6 on MASTER:31010]
```

if I do something like this (dividing the column into join) it works:

```
SELECT t1.anum as anum, COUNT(*) as callCount, SUM(dur*1) as callDuration, COUNT(distinct bnum) as voiceBnumCount, t2.longCallCount
FROM hdfs4.`/cdr2p2/{181129}*` as t1 
JOIN(
    SELECT anum as anum, COUNT(distinct cdrref) as longCallCount
    FROM hdfs4.`/cdr2p2/{181129}*` as t1 WHERE `t1`.`direction` IN ('UP') AND `t1`.`anum_code` IN ('FIRSTANUM') 
    AND CONCAT(sdate, ' ', stime) BETWEEN '18.11.29 14.39.58' AND '18.11.29 17.40.00' 
    GROUP BY (anum) HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30 AND SUM(dur*1)/60 >= 150
) as t2 ON t2.anum = t1.anum
WHERE `t1`.`direction` IN ('UP') AND `t1`.`anum_code` IN ('FIRSTANUM') 
AND CONCAT(sdate, ' ', stime) BETWEEN '18.11.29 14.39.58' AND '18.11.29 17.40.00' 
GROUP BY (t1.anum, t2.longCallCount) HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30 AND SUM(dur*1)/60 >= 150
LIMIT 10
```

What cause this? Is because too many aggregation while only 1 grouping?
How do I solve it?

Comment: It looks lile a bug. Can you provide a dataset to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @VitaliiDiravka i can't, because data confidentiality, and too big. But I can give you what's data is look like.

anum is phone number.
dur is duration, sometimes the value can be blank.
bnum is phone number.
cdrref is random string, can be same with multiple records, can be blank.

Comment: and it will reproduced if data is not found from having.
like, if SUM(dur*1)/60 >= 1 it will return the result. if there's no result then it will fail

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Moreover it can be regression after DRILL-6027. It is necessary to verify it on Drill 1.13.

Please create a Jira ticket and provide logs, logical plan and the minimum data to reproduce the issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL

Comment: hi again.. how do I get the logical plan from query? is this the way: EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <query> ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also you can find it in Drill WEB UI in Profiles -> Query->Physical plan.